# Turning a query formula into a working formula

Tags: excel, vba

i need to turn a dynamic formula, made of a query into a real, working formula somehow. The formula looks as follows:

```
=INDEX('C:\EXCHANGER\[FracReport.xlsb]ProppantAndFluid'!B57;1;1)
```

And despite that it starts with "=" it does nothing until i do ctrl+H, replace "=" with "=". The VBA solution that i have found so far:

```
Dim a As String
Dim b As String
Dim c As String


Sheets("ProppantAndFluid").UsedRange.Replace What:="=", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart
a = "="
b = ActiveSheet.Range("B10").Value
c = a & b

MsgBox c
ActiveSheet.Range("F10") = c
```

It msgboxes c alright, but when it comes to the actual concatenation of "=" and formula and assigning it to a range, it throws

> Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

Any solutions for query obtained formulas, or workarounds for Application, object defined errors, please?

Comment: what's the outcome of `MsgBox c`?

Comment: =INDEX('C:\EXCHANGER\[FracReport.xlsb]ProppantAndFluid'!B57;1;1)

Comment: try replacing all ";" to ",". and there's a "\" missing between "EXHANGER" and "[FRAC..."

Comment: *ActiveSheet.Range("F10") = c* should be `ActiveSheet.Range("F10").Formula = c`

Comment: @Variatus, that is not an issue: `.Value` property is implicitly assumed and it works as `.Formula` one, provided the `Value` meets formula syntax requirements, of course

Comment: @HTH You are facing an error 1004 which implies that a functionality of Excel doesn't function as expected. Perhaps it's the one you point to.

Comment: @Variatus, may be is the one I point to (let's wait for Andrey feedback), but once you have a valid formula syntax the `Value` property acts as `Formula`

Comment: @HTH, replacing all ";" to "," has actually worked in a way, it did assemble =INDEX('C:\EXCHANGER\[FracReport.xlsb]ProppantAndFluid'!B57;1;1), yet under #name? error. But i have noticed a thing, that when you F2+Enter on the cell, it actually returns working formula. However adding VBA snippet for F2+Enter prompts the window that would normally pop up when you press F2 key in VBE, and no result on question

Comment: @Variatus, yes, you're right, both Range.formula = c and Range = c work just fine

Comment: @To all, i finally found the way of turning assembled =INDEX formula into working one, each range should be added with equasion Range("B10").FormulaLocal = Range("B10").FormulaLocal

Answer (score 0):

Thanx everyone for your help and giving me a good path for solving the problem, the ultimate code that makes a query generated formula work is this:

```
Dim a As String
Dim b As String
Dim c As String


Sheets("ProppantAndFluid").UsedRange.Replace What:="=", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart
Sheets("ProppantAndFluid").UsedRange.Replace What:=";", Replacement:=",", 
LookAt:=xlPart
a = "="
b = ActiveSheet.Range("B10").Value
c = a & b

ActiveSheet.Range("B10") = c
Range("B10").FormulaLocal = Range("B10").FormulaLocal
```